# Eigen LU solve diagonal right hand side compile error

Tags: eigen, eigen3

I use Eigen to do dense linear algebra computation, however with the vector as diagonal right hand side, the code doesn't compile(complaining stride)?

```
EigenMatrix A, B, X;
EigenVector C;

X= A.lu.solve(B);               // ok
X= A.lu.solve(C.asDiagonal());  // not ok !
```

Answer (score 1):

`asDiagonal()` returns a wrapper object which doesn't match expected type of the
`solve()` method, so you need to construct an actual object of the matrix type
around it like in:

```
EigenMatrix(C.asDiagonal())
```

This works for me (the syntax is different, since your code doesn't compile for me, maybe because of different version/interface):

```cpp
#include "Eigen/Core"
#include "Eigen/LU"

int
main()
{
    Eigen::Matrix4d A, B, X;
    Eigen::Vector4d C;

    X = A.lu().solve(B);
    X = A.lu().solve(Eigen::Matrix4d(C.asDiagonal()));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: With reasonably recent versions your code will generate a static assertion: THIS_FUNCTION_IS_NOT_FOR_INTEGER_NUMERIC_TYPES, since LU decompostion requires division (without truncation).